# Optimising a C Algorithm having ported to Python

Tags: python, c, optimization, signal-processing

I would like to write a Real-time Audio to Pitch algorithm in Python and it looks like the Yin Algorithm solves this problem. I have found a number of C implementations of Yin, and having tried one of them out on my voice it works as expected and in real time. I have started porting it to Python but I can see that it is around 100 times slower - so no longer real.time. I am using a 2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7.

Below is a simulation of the algorithm, in both C and Python, to give an idea of the computation involved. Each simulation is calculating the pitch for 90,000 samples. The C function takes 2 seconds and the Python 200 seconds to complete.

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int buffer_length = 150;
    float sec = 0;
    float* buffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*buffer_length);
    
    clock_t before = clock();

    int j;
    int16_t tau;
    int16_t i;
    float delta;
    
    for(j = 0; j < 90000; j++){
        for(tau = 0 ; tau < 75; tau++){
            for(i = 0; i < 75; i++){
                delta = buffer[i] - buffer[i + tau];
                buffer[tau] += delta * delta;
            }
        }    
    }
    
    clock_t difference = clock() - before;
    sec = difference / (float )CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f\n",sec);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Python code**

```
import time

buffer = [0.0]*150

ts = time.time()

for j in range(90000):
    for tau in range(75):
        for i in range(75):
            delta = buffer[i] - buffer[i + tau]
            buffer[tau] += delta * delta

print(time.time()-ts)
```

I was thinking of using a sampling rate of 8KHz but possibly a higher rate if possible. Should it be possible to vastly improve the performance of the Python code and if so how would I go about doing this? If not, then I guess writing a C library with a Python Wrapper is my only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). The issue is that python for loops are *significantly* slower than C loops. Using numba you should be able to speed them up quite dramatically since you've written them yourself and there are no external dependencies (which have been known to mess with numba).

Just use the njit decorator and wrap your nested for loops in a function.

Comment: I wrapped everything in a function and it took ~88 seconds to execute on my laptop. I then decorated it with `numba.njit`, and it took 2.27 seconds. Very nice!

Comment: @MattDMo Yes that was an amazing difference!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python is considerably slower than C for many applications.  Those requiring a lot of numeric computation are some of the worst cases.  There are multiple approaches to such problems.

Writing an extension directly in C is the old-school way, and it might be particularly attractive to you since you already have C code.  There are tools that can help with that, such as swig.

Alternatively, you may be able to express the wanted computation well enough using Numpy.  Or there is Cython, either for writing a version of the algorithm or for wrapping the C implementation of it.

The key thing you want to do is avoid converting between native and Python numeric representations.  Keep all your numbers native.

Comment: I started programming in C but its been a long time. Since there isn't a huge amount of code to port I'm going to try the numba approach first to see how I get on.